# How can I remove nonoverlapping values after comparing two datasets in r?

Tags: r

I am a beginner R user and I have been having trouble coding for one of my research classes. I am studying if there is a relationship between terrorist organization's recruitment strategy and the level of violence they employ. I have found two datasets so far. PPTUS dataset has values for my explanatory variable, which is terrorist recruitment strategy. GTD dataset has values for my dependent variables, which are fatalities, number of incidents, etc. I am trying to run multiple regression analysis, but I have trouble cleaning up and merging the datasets. I think the problem is that these two datasets have different unit of analysis; GTD records all terrorist incidents by date while PPTUS lists characteristics and information of terrorist organizations that had conducted acts of terrorism within US soil.

To make data analysis more manageable, I would like to remove organizations that do not overlap in both datasets. So far, this is what I have:

[image: photo]

Based on the match, I would like to drop [FALSE] values from the observation.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: Can you do something along the lines of a `left_join` and remove the nulls?